# Is it possible to show that a particular theorem or its negation is provable, without knowing which of the two is true?

Tags: logic, computer-science, incompleteness, turing-machines, open-problem

I've been thinking about this for a while: as far as we know, is it possible that **for a particular** statement $\sigma$ of $\textsf{ZFC}$, we can prove that $(\textsf{ZFC} \vdash \sigma) \vee (\textsf{ZFC} \vdash \neg\sigma)$, without providing a proof of $\textsf{ZFC} \vdash \sigma$ or a proof of $\textsf{ZFC} \vdash \neg\sigma$?

Of course this is not true **for all** statements $\sigma$, because $\textsf{ZFC}$ is not even complete (if it is consistent), but maybe this could be true for some specific $\sigma$.

More in general (if $\textsf{ZFC}$ is consistent ;) ), let $\Gamma$ be a set of axioms, and suppose we know that $T(\Gamma)$, the theory of $\Gamma$, is incomplete (and thus consistent). Is it possible that there exists some statement $\sigma$ such that we can show that $(\Gamma \vdash \sigma) \vee (\Gamma \vdash \neg \sigma)$ without proving $\Gamma \vdash \sigma$ nor $\Gamma \vdash \neg \sigma$?

---

I started to think about this some time ago in the specific case of $\textsf{P}$ vs $\textsf{NP}$. Maybe we are struggling to find a proof of $\textsf{P}=\textsf{NP}$ or of $\textsf{P} \neq \textsf{NP}$, when such a proof doesn't actually exist in $\textsf{ZFC}$. Thus it would be nice to be able to prove at least that an answer *does* exist. But maybe this is not possible.

Note that a somewhat "dual" result has already been proven:

> **Theorem (Hartmanis-Hopcroft).** There exists a Turing machine $M$ that halts on every input, such
>   that relative to the oracle $L(M)$, neither $\textsf{P}=\textsf{NP}$ nor $\textsf{P} \neq \textsf{NP}$ is provable in $\textsf{ZF}$, assuming $\textsf{ZF}$ is consistent.

You can find more about this in the paper *Is $\textsf{P}$ Versus $\textsf{NP}$ Formally Independent?* by Scott Aaronson (http://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/pnp.pdf).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question correctly, but how about a statement such as "473289243244732897 is prime"?  I can give a provably terminating algorithm which determines the answer (and, if desired, outputs a proof certifying it) without actually running the algorithm and getting the answer.

Comment: Maybe what he's referring to those theorems for which we don't know a proof, like P=NP: is it even provable?

Answer (score 2):

To continue steven taschuk's suggestion :

Let $N$ be some very big number, from which noone knows whether it is a prime
number or not (for example the $33$-th Fermat-number).

If $N$ is prime or composite, in both cases there is a proof for this statement,
but the result is unknown.

This can be applied to any decidable question whose answer is unknwon.